# Different notation in Expectation's integration in (Empirical) Risk Minimization

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, expected-value, machine-learning, riemann-integration

For the philosophy of Statistical Learning Theory, the Risk Minimization is the focus. We want to minimize
$$
R(f)=\mathbb{E}[L(f(x),y)]=\int~L(f(x),y) ~dP(x,y),
$$
where $P(x,y)$ is the "joint probability distribution".

> Is it "joint probability density/mass function  (pdf/pmf)" or "joint cumulative distribution function (CDF)" ?

I understand $R(f)=\mathbb{E}[L(f(x),y)]$, but I think the integral should be something like
$$
\int_{\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}}~L(f(x),y)~p(x,y)~d??
$$

that $\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}$ is the space of $x,y$, but I don't know how to write the $d??$ thing.

It seems that the $\int~L(f(x),y) ~dP(x,y)$ that $dP(x,y)$ is not the so called "change of variable" in the undergrad calculus that
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g'(x)~dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dg(x),
$$
which is Riemann–Stieltjes integral, $g(x)$ is a CDF, $g'(x)$ is the pdf.

So I guess it is not Riemann-Stieltjes Integral (not the "change of variable (interation by substitution)"), but the Lebesgue Integral? However, I have very little knowledge in Lebesgue Integral and Measure Theory thing.